# Is hiding content by Javascript or jQuery Worth trying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can hide content by using `display:none;` in css. But I read on many websites that Google doesn't like `display:none;`. I really need this because of jQuery animations.
Now I found new method for hiding content through Javascript/jQuery.

```
$(this).css({display:'none'});
```

Is this better than `display:none;`. Is this Google Friendly?
Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TTc4q/)

Comment: it's the same thing, that adds `display:none` as an inline style on the element.

Comment: I think it's better to use the jQuery .hide(), .show(), and .toggle() to show/hide things.  Ultimately, I believe it's simply doing a 'display: none' under the hood.  I agree with @hunter below that you should hide on page load, and not by default.

Comment: But think google bot will not execute javascript. Because of which my content will be Google Friendly.

Comment: @CodeChimp If I use jQuery code mentioned above it will hide content on load and not by default. Is it better because of it?

Comment: I would argue that it's better than just hiding it directly in the CSS, but not as good as using hide/show/toggle.  Using those methods seems to give you some cross-browser compatibility, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @CodeChimp Should i then use `$("#1").hide();` instead of `display:none;`

Comment: Yes.  toggle() is also nice, as you can pass a statement that evaluates to a boolean true/false, and it either shows (true) or hides (false) based on the evaluation, which removes a lot of the common "if(something) { show() } else if(somethingElse) { hide() }"

Comment: @CodeChimp Thanks. I think this is not against Google's terms because if javascript is switched of content will be available. In case of `display:none;` if javascript is switched off content doesn't show up and that is against Google's terms. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know Google's terms of service.  I know, for a developer of Web apps, that you can't assume the user has JS turned on.  I know that, in most cases (obviously, there are exceptions) that if you want something to to be shown, the first option is to just not show it.  The next best thing is to have it default to being shown, but then use JS to hide it.  I would not want to take the other approach  of hiding it by default because if JS is turned off, you will never see it.  Again, there are exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Google has guidelines that you can follow to make your site safe to be crawled:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769

Be aware that the Google bot does understand and execute basic JavaScript on web pages now to see what results a user would actually get to see:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/81766?hl=en

**Here's a snippet about hidden text or links**: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353

> Hiding text or links in your content to manipulate Google’s search
>   rankings can be seen as deceptive and is a violation of Google’s
>   Webmaster Guidelines. **Text (such as excessive keywords) can be
>   hidden in several ways, including**:
>
> - Using white text on a white background Locating text behind an image
> - Using CSS to position text off-screen Setting the font size to 0
> - Hiding a link by only linking one small character—for example, a    hyphen in the middle of a paragraph

Comment: thanks for your help. I created a fiddle have a look over it. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TTc4q/) @alex

Comment: So if you navigate to http://fiddle.jshell.net/TTc4q/show/light/ which is the actual HTML page of your fiddle with the Lynx browser, or with NoScript on Firefox you can see that your text is still visible. The fact that it can be seen by clicking is good. Google only forbids things that always stay hidden and are only there to increase SEO.

Comment: So I was right about it. We should use javascript to hide content instead of `display:none;`.

Comment: @mwaseema Almost. It means whether you use CSS or JavaScript to hide the text, you need to make sure that there is some way the user/GoogleBot can see the text. If it is permanently hidden on the page your site will be penalized by the GoogleBot.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue to me is that if you hide it in the css and then use javascript to show it, visitors without javascript enabled will not be able to view the content. Using `$(this).css({display:'none'});` to hide the content will ensure that it will display by default for those without javascript enabled.

This issue comes up often in trying to avoid a flash of unstyled content. Good discussion and solutions provide at http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content

Comment: Well, using this jquery code will not hide code if user is with javascript disabled. And this is according to the Google's terms. They want content to be visible in all conditions.

Comment: Right, if a user has javascript disabled, the content will be shown. That way they will still be able to view the content of your website.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS display:none is perfectly fine for google.  The JS way won't offer you any benefits, SEO-wise.
Here's one example: http://seotesttool.com/blog/does-the-google-bot-index-css-hidden-divs/

However, the problem arises if you hide content (by either of these methods) that is solely for the purpose of tricking google... keyword stuffing, spammy links, etc.  Then you are likely to get penalized and removed from Google's index all together, and you will have to go through a manual process to fix your site and wait for it to be verified and re-added.  So as long as you are not planning this sort of scheme, and you're just doing a normal hide/show of user-friendly content, you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard, content within a `display: none;` block does not get read by search spiders and screen readers.  If you use javascript to hide it (even via `.css()` or `.hide()` methods) you'll be hiding it after the spiders have crawled the page.

The downside is that there also may be a flash before the js loads where you can see the hidden content.  Try using the [`.visuallyhidden` convention](http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/) if you want computers to read through your content.